# Why is the order of the output different everytime I run this program?

Tags: java, multithreading, operating-system

Why is the order of the output different everytime I run this program? Is it due to more than one thread attempting to access a shared resource at the same time. So therefore the it will be random the way the threads are executed?

My output

java MyThreadExample
    Hello from thread 1
    Hello from thread 3
    Hello from thread 4
    Hello from thread 2

java MyThreadExample
    Hello from thread 1
    Hello from thread 3
    Hello from thread 2
    Hello from thread 4

```
java MyThreadExample
Hello from thread 1
Hello from thread 4
Hello from thread 3
Hello from thread 2
```

code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;

class MyThreadExample {

public static void main(String[] args) {
   HelloThread ht1 = new HelloThread(1);
   HelloThread ht2 = new HelloThread(2);
   HelloThread ht3 = new HelloThread(3);
   HelloThread ht4 = new HelloThread(4);
   ht1.start();
   ht2.start();
   ht3.start();
   ht4.start();
   }
}

class HelloThread extends Thread {
    int threadID;

    HelloThread(int threadID) {
    this.threadID = threadID;
    }

    public void run() {
    System.out.println("Hello from thread " + this.threadID);
    }
} // end Thread
```

Comment: Its related to OS. Once thread starts Os schedule the threads. Some gets high priority some gets low priority.

Comment: You should read the basics of concurrency/multi threading before writing any such code. If you do that, then you won't have this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are absolutely right and that was because of the multi-threading.

You started 4 threads and each of them went on their own - there was no logic sequence between them, thus any of them might finish first and any of them might finish last. The sequence you observe is entirely random and can be different from time to time.

"Is it due to more than one thread attempting to access a shared resource at the same time. " that was actually irrelevant in the context, since there is really no resource shared among them.

Comment: What about `System.out`?